# Adding different string arrays into List<String[]>, but returning the same value

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

I am having a database file written to a `bus_stopdb.properties` file. It looks like this: (This is a part of the file)

```
2X-bound1-stop0-stopcode=CH42W09500
2B-bound1-stop2-stopseq=2
11C-bound2-stop14-stopname=\u725B\u982D\u89D2\u9435\u8DEF\u7AD9
11D-bounds=2
13D-bound2-stop31-stopcode=SA14S32000
11D-bound1-stop17-stopname=\u89C0\u5858\u78BC\u982D
11D-bound2-stop9-stopcode=KW16W22500
2A-bound1-stop29-stopcode=ME01T11000
14D-bound1-stop18-stopcode=LE01W13000
11X-bound1-stop12-stopseq=12
16-bound1-stop3-stopseq=3
23M-bound1-stop12-stopseq=12
```

And I am going to load the content of the properties file to a `List<String[]>`. But I am issuing a problem that is the content of the `List` is all the **same**. Here's a function to load the file:

```
public static boolean loadDatabase(boolean fromClassResources){
        try {
            File file;
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            InputStream in;
            if (fromClassResources){
                in = KmbApi.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("bus_stopdb.properties");
            } else
            {
                file = new File("bus_stopdb.properties");
                if(!file.exists()){
                        return false;
                }
                in = new FileInputStream(file);
            }
            prop.load(in);
            int buses = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("buses"));
            int bounds;
            int stops;
            String[] data = new String[5];
            for (int i = 0; i < buses; i++){
                data[0] = bus_db[i];
                bounds = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty(bus_db[i] + "-bounds"));
                for (int j = 1; j <= bounds; j++){
                    System.out.println("Bus: " + bus_db[i] + " Bound: " + j);
                    try {
                        stops = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty(bus_db[i] + "-bound" + j + "-stops"));
                    } catch (NullPointerException e){
                        continue;
                    }
                    data[1] = Integer.toString(j);
                    for (int s = 0; s < stops; s++){
                        data[2] = prop.getProperty(bus_db[i] + "-bound" + j + "-stop" + s + "-stopcode");
                        data[3] = prop.getProperty(bus_db[i] + "-bound" + j + "-stop" + s + "-stopseq");
                        data[4] = prop.getProperty(bus_db[i] + "-bound" + j + "-stop" + s + "-stopname");
                        //Printing the building array
                        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(data));
                        busstop_pair.add(data);
                    }
                }
            }
            //Printing the arrays in the List<String[]>
            System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(busstop_pair.toArray()));
            in.close();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The first `println` is giving me a correct result (different result).
But the second `println` is giving me a invaild result, they are all the same!

I couldn't figure out what happened with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding the same array multiple times to the List. You have to create a new array for each iteration of the loop in order to have different elements in your List :

```
                for (int s = 0; s < stops; s++){
                    data = new String[5];
                    data[0] = bus_db[i];
                    data[1] = Integer.toString(j);
                    data[2] = prop.getProperty(bus_db[i] + "-bound" + j + "-stop" + s + "-stopcode");
                    data[3] = prop.getProperty(bus_db[i] + "-bound" + j + "-stop" + s + "-stopseq");
                    data[4] = prop.getProperty(bus_db[i] + "-bound" + j + "-stop" + s + "-stopname");
                    //Printing the building array
                    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(data));
                    busstop_pair.add(data);
                }
```

Comment: Oh, thanks. I figured out the problem now. It works very well. I am sorry about that Stack overflow requires me to wait 8 minutes to accept a answer.